# Optimizing images inside View Pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview, android-image, android-memory

I am having `ViewPager` with around 10 pages. All pages have images of resolution more than 1000x2000. Basically width of the images are different for different images. As I was not able to place images of more than size 2048 width so I used 2 images(divided one single image to 2 images).So each page has 2 images and other views as well.

I tried many ways of optimizing but could able to optimize much.
I tried making `ImageView` null and even setting its bitmap to null and even removing all views and making them null in on destroy and  [Optimize bitmaps inside ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html)

In this I am using `Asyntask` to load images on screen. And even tried storing images in Cache. But still facing memory related issues.

Needs suggestion to how can I optimize more and avoid out of memory.

Comment: Are you re-sizing the images? croping? scaling?

Comment: @MichaelLiberman : No...I am not croping or scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by having `AsyncTask` to load images from resource. And after loading from memory I store it in LRU cache. And then I retrieve it from cache.

In `doInBackgroud()` I have:

```
BitmapFactory.Options mOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    mOptions.inPurgeable = true;
    mOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    mOptions.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = false;
    mOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    mOptions.inScaled = true;



        SoftReference<Bitmap> bm = new SoftReference<Bitmap>(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getApplicationContext().getResources(), data,
                        mOptions));
        return bm.get();
```

With this, I am recycling images in `onDestroy()` and making `Bitmap` to null.